# Switching between frames in tkinter, clock app

Tags: python, tkinter

Good day, guys. I've got a problem with switching between frames in tkinter. I'm trying to make a clock app with time, stopwatch, timer and alarm. If I click on the first frame it's working, but if I select the second frame it's breaks. The previous frame just don't open because the second frame refreshing too fast (lbl.after). Can you help me with switching between frames?

[image: switching between frames]

```
from tkinter import *
from tkmacosx import *
from time import strftime

root = Tk()
root.title('Time')
root.geometry('500x500')
root.resizable(False, False)

counter = -1
running = False

def time_frame():
    string = strftime("%H:%M:%S %A %d %Y")
    frame_time = Frame(root, width = 480, height = 410, bg = 'gray70')
    frame_time.place(x = 10, y = 80)
    lbl1 = Label(frame_time, text = list, width = 32, height = 10, font = ('Arial', 25))
    lbl1.place(x = 10, y = 80)
    lbl1.config(text=string)
    lbl1.after(1000, time_frame)

def stopwatch_frame():
    frame_stopwatch = Frame(root, width = 480, height = 410, bg = 'gray70')
    frame_stopwatch.place(x = 10, y = 80)
    lbl2 = Label(frame_stopwatch, text = '0', width = 25, height = 5, font = ('Arial', 25))
    lbl2.place(x = 10, y = 80)
    start_button = Button(frame_stopwatch, width = 80, height = 40, text = 'Start')
    start_button.place(x = 10, y = 240)
    stop_button = Button(frame_stopwatch, width = 80, height = 40, text = 'Stop')
    stop_button.place(x = 100, y = 240)
    reset_button = Button(frame_stopwatch, width = 80, height = 40, text = 'Reset')
    reset_button.place(x = 190, y = 240)
    lbl2.after(1, stopwatch_frame)

frame_top = Frame(root, width = 500, height = 70, bg = 'gray64')
frame_top.place(x = 0, y = 0)

time_btn = Button(frame_top, text = 'Time', width = 50, height = 50, command = time_frame)
time_btn.place(x = 10, y = 10)

stopwatch_btn = Button(frame_top, text = 'Stopwatch', width = 50, height = 50, font = ('Arial', 9), command = stopwatch_frame)
stopwatch_btn.place(x = 80, y = 10)

timer_btn = Button(frame_top, text = 'Timer', width = 50, height = 50)
timer_btn.place(x = 150, y = 10)

alarm_btn = Button(frame_top, text = 'Alarm', width = 50, height = 50)
alarm_btn.place(x = 220, y = 10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @TheLizzard can you show me how to do this please?

Comment: I note you're using `after` but i don't see any `after_cancel`.

Comment: thank you all gentlemen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified example of a clock and stop watch class.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkmacosx import *
from time import strftime, process_time

class timer:

    delaya = None
    delayb = None

    def __init__( self ):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title('Time')
        self.buttona = tk.Button( self.root, text = 'clock', width = 40, command = self.setclock )
        self.buttonb = tk.Button( self.root, text = 'watch', width = 40, command = self.setwatch )
        self.buttona.grid( row=0, column=0, sticky='ew' )
        self.buttonb.grid( row=0, column=1, sticky='ew' )
        self.root.update_idletasks()
        self.root.resizable( False, False )

    def clock( self ):
        self.root.after_cancel( self.delaya )
        self.delaya = None
        self.buttona[ 'text' ] = strftime("%H:%M:%S %A %d %Y")
        self.delaya = self.root.after( 1000, self.clock )

    def watch( self ):
        self.root.after_cancel( self.delayb )
        self.delayb = None
        self.buttonb[ 'text' ] = f'{process_time():0.5f}'
        self.delayb = self.root.after( 1, self.watch )

    def setclock( self ):
        if self.delaya == None:
            self.delaya = self.root.after( 1000, self.clock )
        else:
            self.root.after_cancel( self.delaya )
            self.delaya = None
            self.buttona[ 'text' ] = 'clock'

    def setwatch( self ):
        if self.delayb == None:
            self.delayb = self.root.after( 1, self.watch )
        else:
            self.root.after_cancel( self.delayb )
            self.delayb = None
            self.buttonb[ 'text' ] = 'watch'

if __name__ == '__main__':

    device = timer( )
    tk.mainloop()
```